# PHP PDO and DELETE with in() not working

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Here is the code for the class:

```
    class Delete_Category extends Category {

    private $idchain = array();

    public function __construct($id) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->check_id($id);
        $this->get_delete_ids($this->id);
        $this->delete_category($this->idchain);
    }
```

// Get all the Children IDs from the DB and store them in the array

```
    private function get_delete_ids($id) {
        $this->query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM `shop_categories` WHERE parent_id = :id");
        $this->query->execute(array("id" => $id));
        while($result = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $this->get_delete_ids($result['id']);
        }
        $this->idchain[]= $id;
    }
```

// Implode the array into an id string and throw it in the query

```
    private function delete_category($id_array) {
        $id = implode(",",$id_array);
        try {
            $this->query = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `shop_categories` WHERE id IN (:id)");
            $this->query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            // log it{
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that this always ends up with only the last ID being deleted. The query seems to be working however because it looks totaly fine if i echo it and replace :id with $id.

// SQL output string if echoed:

```
DELETE FROM `shop_categories` WHERE id IN (11,6)
```

// If i manually add this to the Database it works as intended so the problem has to be somewhere at the PDO statement... Can anyone help me?

Comment: There are a few places where you cannot use prepared statement variables, this is one of them. The other two (that I know of) is `limit` and `offset`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for that:

```
DELETE FROM `shop_categories` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, :id)"
```

Comment: Why is it working with the find in set and not with just in ?

Comment: @guy_fawkes The `IN` operator expects a *list of values* while a parameter in a prepared statement can only hold *one single value*. In contrast to that, the `FIND_IN_SET` function expects the second parameter to be a *single string value* (which then holds a list of values).