# PHP PDO Delete from array

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have an array of GUIDs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1770302746_580821208_2068022554_1652435499
    [1] => 595039408_884272175_1344680100_1997277231
    ...
)
```

which I implode to a comma serparated string*:

```
1770302746_580821208_2068022554_1652435499,595039408_884272175_1344680100_1997277231
```

that I then pass to a sql DELETE statement:

```
$q=$conn->prepare(" DELETE FROM su_posts_att_sort WHERE FileGUID IN ({$GUIDs}) ");
$q->execute();
```

No rows are deleted however. Placing try / catch blocks to return any exception has not thrown any. Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

*Have also tried with each GUID enclosed in double quotes.

**EDIT**
Here is the submitted sql:

```
DELETE FROM su_posts_att_sort WHERE FileGUID IN ('1770302746_580821208_2068022554_1652435499','595039408_884272175_1344680100_1997277231')
```

Works fine through the console...

Comment: are you putting quotes around the ids? they are most likely considered strings which need to be quoted.

Comment: without quotes, those'll be interepted as wonky/bad integers, and mysql will be looking for `1770302746` and `595039408`, ignoring the rest as garbage.

Comment: Have tried with the following, using both single and double quotes: `$GUIDs = "\'".implode("\',\'", $_POST['arrDeleted'])."\'";`

Comment: @Eamonn Try echoing the resulting SQL and adding it to the question.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Just updated the question

Comment: Anything to do with the answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539683/php-pdo-and-delete-with-in-not-working?rq=1)?

Comment: @Eamonn Your query looks ok, and I can't see any explanation for the behaviour in the code you posted. Are you sure the connection is valid, and that you're not in a transaction that may roll back?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson No, no transactions. I really can't see the issue myself. As the console is allowing it through in it's raw state, there must be an issue with how the PDO formats the string.

Comment: @Eamonn If you're echoing the string as is when you finished building it, PDO should not reformat anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes, not double quotes, and certainly not unquoted -- they contain underscores, so they are definitely strings, not numerics.

But rather than just adding quotes, it would be better to use the `PDO::quote` method, as this will guarantee that they are using the right quoting, no matter what DB you're using, and no matter what weird characters might be lurking in the data.

You can apply `PDO::quote` to all the elements in the array in a single line of code, along with the `implode()` by using `array_map()`. Something like this:

```
$guids = implode(',', array_map(array($pdo,'quote'), $guidArray));
```

Comment: Have tried `$GUIDs = implode(array_map(array($conn,'quote'), $_POST['arrDeleted']));` without effect. This looks a very efficient method however...

Comment: I notice that the resultant string is not comma separated, would it not need to be?

Comment: @Eamonn Yes, it needs to be comma separated.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson How would I achieve this, using this method? It's not one I've used before...

Comment: @Eamonn If I remember correctly, just add a string with a comma, `','` as a first parameter, and it'll implode with a comma as separator.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yup, just `implode(',',array_map(array($conn,'quote'), $_POST['arrDeleted']));`. Still didn't have any effect however. The curly braces in the sql are necessary for a string, right?

Comment: edited to include the comma separator. Careless of me to miss that. But yes, this technique is efficient.

Comment: @Eamonn - by 'curly braces', you mean the ones from your original code? they're part of the PHP syntax, not SQL syntax. In fact, in this case, they are optional, but it is recommended to use them in all cases when embedding PHP variables in strings. It's not always necessary, but it is sometimes, and it helps to be consistent with these things.